# Cocoa/Obj-C - Count elements in XML file

Tags: objective-c, xml, macos, cocoa

Got an application wich read some infos in a specific XML file.
I would like to add one more option, here is the description:

Here is an example of my XML type file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Report>
    <ReportCreationDate>20110307162840</ReportCreationDate>
    <ReportTitle>Title sample</ReportTitle>
    <ReportDescription>Description sample</ReportDescription>
    <Videos>
        <Video>
            <VideoTitle>Video 1</VideoTitle>
            <VideoDescription>Video description sample</VideoDescription>
        </Video>
        <Video>
            <VideoTitle>Video 2</VideoTitle>
            <VideoDescription>Video description sample</VideoDescription>
        </Video>
    </Videos>
</Report>
```

I would like to count how many `<Video>` elements is there in the `<Videos>` node.

For this example it's **2**

How can I do that? Using NSXMLDocument?

I would like to write the result in a TextField.


Example: 
XML file contains **5** videos.



If someone can help, it would be great!

Thanks in advance

Miskia

(and sorry for my poor english, i'm a frenchy :p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get the job done. I'll leave the error handling up to you.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToYourXMLFile];

NSError *error = nil;

NSXMLDocument *document = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

if(!error)
{   
    NSXMLElement *rootElement = [document rootElement];

    NSUInteger count = [[rootElement nodesForXPath:@"//Video" error:&error] count];

    if(!error)
    {
        NSString *videosCount = nil;

        if(count == 0)
            videosCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"XML file contains no videos."];
        else if(count == 1)
            videosCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"XML file contains 1 video."];
        else
            videosCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"XML file contains %d videos.", count];

        [myTextField setStringValue:videosCount];
    }
}

[document release]
```

Comment: Ok i had it to work... One more question, is it possible to add an option for example: if there is only one video, in the text field there is no "s" for "video" and if there is more than one video, there is a "s" to "videos" ?

Comment: I've updated the code. This could be cleaned up a bit. Please accept the answer if it solves the problem.